# Insertion of rows without changing formulas on other sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have two separate spreadsheets which feed each other (one person completes the main one so all others autofill).

I have set up formulas so it autofills but when I insert new lines into the main spreadsheet the other spreadsheet takes information from the wrong line, even though the new data was put in the place of the old data.
(The new inserted lines were put in where the data was before).

can anyone help me to "protect" the formulas from movement?

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: You say the sheets "feed each other" but then say the others fill off the main one. Does the main sheet also feed off the others? Or do all the other sheets feed off the main sheet only? Can you also give us an example what formula you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the arguments in your formula to change when new rows are inserted on the source sheet, you may have to use the `INDIRECT` function.

For example, if your formula is

```
=SUM(Sheet1!A1:A5)
```

you can use the following instead to protect against changes to your formula.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1:A5"))
```

This is useful only if you have a small number of formulas you want to protect. If you have several filled-down formulas, this could get tedious because you'll have to edit the argument of the `INDIRECT` function manually for each one.